# Pandas sliding window with step size

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is there any fast way to have an overlapping sliding windows with step size in Pandas? I'm trying to get aggregate metrics (like mean, standard deviation, percentiles, ecc.) along each column in a window of 60 seconds and step size 1 (windows can overlap).

I'll write a minimal example to explain what I want.

Suppose we have the following dataframe obtained with `tmp = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,4,5])`

```
>>> tmp
   0
0  1
1  2
2  3
3  4
4  5
```

With a window of 2, step size 1 and mean as an aggregate, I want this result

```
     0
0  1.5
1  2.5
2  3.5
3  4.5
```

My dataframe has roughly 200000 rows and 870 columns, so I'd like a fast solution.
Pandas' rolling function does not seem to have a step size parameter.
I tried reading similar questions, but I didn't find a fitting solution.

Thanks for your help.

EDIT:
I tried solutions like `df[columname].groupby(df.index // 60).std()`, but windows do not overlap and the stride/step size isn't 1.

EDIT 2: I'd like a general solution that works with any step size.

New example with mean, window 3 and step size 2: same initial dataframe `tmp = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,4,5])`.
In this case the output should be:

```
   0
0  2
1  4
```

Basically the window takes the first 3 values (1, 2 and 3), computes the mean, than skips 2 positions (in this case values 1 and 2) and computes the mean of the other 3 values (in this case 3, 4 and 5).

If anyone reading this is searching for a solution with step size 1, @Roy2012 pointed out a solution that works in that specific case.

Comment: What do you mean by step size? Could you please provide an example for output (and input, if needed) that has a different step size?

Comment: I added the new output example in the edit 2 part. Sorry for not being clear from the beginning and thanks anyway for the time you dedicated.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for (in this example, at least) is called rolling mean:

```
tmp.rolling(2).mean()

==>
     0
0  NaN
1  1.5
2  2.5
3  3.5
4  4.5
```

If you looking for a larger window and less results, as in the second example above, do the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(range(1, 6)) # 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
df = df.rolling(3, center = True).mean()
# now select every second element. 
df[(df.index % 2) == 1]
```

The result is:

```
     0
1  2.0
3  4.0
```

Comment: Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: I'm testing it on my dataframe, it seems it will take a while before I can inspect the results. `df[columname].groupby(df.index // 60).std()` was way faster, although it wasn't what I was searching for.

Comment: What if I want another stride/step size different than 1?

Comment: Not sure I understand. What's the expected output?

Comment: for example, with the same initial dataframe, but window of size 3, step size of 2 and mean as an operation, the result should be 2 in the first row and 4 in the second row.

Basically (1+2+3)/3 and then (3+4+5)/3 in this example.

Comment: Just change the rolling window size from 2 to 3. Btw, in my answer solves your original question, it would be great if you could accept it.

Comment: That's the point, I can change the window size but not the step size. Maybe I should edit the answer to make clear that I want a general solution with any step size.
Anyway I upvoted your answer, but it doesn't show it publicly 'cause I still have low reputation (below 15).

Comment: You don’t need to upvote, but rather accept. Click the check mark next to my answer. Thanks.